# Is there a way to filter/limit the fields returned from a kubernetes REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, kubernetes

In order to display a dashboard which has the count of the number if certain kinds of resources in kubernetes we need to query the REST API.

For example:  If we need to count the number of secrets across all namespaces you have to query every namespace with a REST call like the following

> GET serverurl:port/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets

Which returns a large JSON response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Audit-Id: d8cee777-36e8-4701-8fa4-458a1fd97c00
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 00:10:03 GMT
Portainer-Agent: 2.16.2
Portainer-Agent-Api-Version: 2
Portainer-Agent-Platform: 2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: c7548afd-c218-4585-a126-2c2eef24b173
X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: a127b956-d11a-40f5-910f-bb6ec5a43216
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "kind": "SecretList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "2844355"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "sh.helm.release.v1.nfs-provisioner.v1",
        "namespace": "default",
        "uid": "baf592c1-4955-41fe-ac73-a0cfc73fa360",
        "resourceVersion": "107753",
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-11-18T00:35:47Z",
        "labels": {
          "modifiedAt": "1668731747",
          "name": "nfs-provisioner",
          "owner": "helm",
          "status": "failed",

...
```

I then count the number of items and basically throw away everything else.
The problem is, I don't need all that information.  It's the classic overfetching problem of REST API's.

I had thought perhaps fieldSelector might do it.  But it doesn't look like it.  Is there a known method?  Because currently across 8 namespaces and 800 config maps and secrets we're fetching 32MB+ of data and that's compressed.   This means the dashboard is taking about 30+ seconds to load.  The other option is to have it load async in the background.   But unless there is a way to reduce how much data is returned I'm thinking about applying a limit and putting something like 500+ instead of an exact count.  Because loading 30MB each time is just terrible.

Comment: Fetching item by item is always going to be painful for large collections of items.  At least you're spared the horror of SOAP.  Reducing the fields won't make much difference, you'll still have the overhead of making the requests and the headers in each response. you need an API that builds the collection server-side, preferably with a paging mechanism.  (Sorry I'm not aware of such a call, if no one else is perhaps it's time for a feature request?)

Comment: This time.  But in my old job, no.   Someone jumped on the XML bandwagon. :(

Comment: We're going to do exactly this.  Build a new api server side to provide what is needed.  That should reduce egress traffic and improve performance dramatically

Comment: Text compresses very well, so if your server isn't already using gzip encoding you might look at returning a zip archive or gzip base64 payload for the set of records instead of raw json text.  If the server already gzips then it probably won't help to double compress and might actually increase the response size.

Comment: Actually the 32MB data is after compression!  So you can see how big of a problem this is.